# How to increase the return result for the agg result list

Tags: elasticsearch

I am currently using elasticsearch 6.4.
I use the aggs query result. details are below.
For some of the query statement, I didn't get what I wanted and miss the document what I am looking for. Elastic search seems to return with a kind of upper bound limit, so that return some top part, not the whole part. So sometimes I am missing what I want from the search result. I am currently doubting that this effect is closely related to the doc_count_error_upper_bound. Is my guess right? Then, how I can reduce the doc_count_error_upper_bound and sum_other_doc_count during aggregation to get what I want? Is there any way to adjust the value?

```
    q = {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": {"query_string": {"default_field": "eLabel", "query": "Trump"}},
                "must_not": [],
                "should": []
            }
        },
        "size": 0,
        "_source": [
            "eid"
        ],
        "aggs": {
            "eids": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "eid"
                }
            }
        }
```

result example

```
{
"took": 21,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
"total": 5,
"successful": 5,
"skipped": 0,
"failed": 0
},
"hits": {
"total": 1103,
"max_score": 0,
"hits": [ ]
},
"aggregations": {
"eids": {
"doc_count_error_upper_bound": 15,
"sum_other_doc_count": 840,
"buckets": [
{
"key": "Q8684",
"doc_count": 62
}
,
{
"key": "Q1062177",
"doc_count": 36
}
,
{
"key": "Q100852",
"doc_count": 25
}
,
{
"key": "Q17469",
"doc_count": 25
}
,
{
"key": "Q39913",
"doc_count": 24
}
,
{
"key": "Q20398",
"doc_count": 22
}
,
{
"key": "Q157169",
"doc_count": 20
}
,
{
"key": "Q36929",
"doc_count": 17
}
,
{
"key": "Q17503",
"doc_count": 16
}
,
{
"key": "Q45086",
"doc_count": 16
}
]
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here query size doesn't work for aggregation, you have to define the size inside the `terms` aggregation.

Please find the below query to get more result.

You can use `size` in `aggregation`, but you can not use `offset` here to retrieve the data that means you can change the limit only. 
Suppose you want 10 lists, after that you need next 10 docs, then you can get next document by passing size 20.

```
 {
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {"query_string": {"default_field": "eLabel", "query": "Trump"}},
            "must_not": [],
            "should": []
        }
    },
    "size": 0,
    "_source": [
        "eid"
    ],
    "aggs": {
        "eids": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "eid",
                "size": 20
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add [`size`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-size) field in your aggregation query. Default value is `10` that is why it is showing only 10 result.

The higher this value the lesser you'll see value of `sum_other_doc_count`. Based on the above link, *when there are lots of unique terms, Elasticsearch only returns the top terms; this number is the sum of the document counts for all buckets that are not part of the response*

```
{  
   q =   {  
      "query":{  
         "bool":{  
            "must":{  
               "query_string":{  
                  "default_field":"eLabel",
                  "query":"Trump"
               }
            },
            "must_not":[  

            ],
            "should":[  

            ]
         }
      },
      "size":0,
      "_source":[  
         "eid"
      ],
      "aggs":{  
         "eids":{  
            "terms":{  
               "field":"eid",
               "size":100,                            <---- Add this
               "show_term_doc_count_error": true      <---- Add this
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Note that document counts are approximate as mentioned [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-approximate-counts). There's no easy way to know which documents are errored out, however there is a way to know that for which buckets, the error would have occurred using `"show_term_doc_count_error": true`. You can read about this [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_calculating_document_count_error).

Hope this helps!